# Running Groovy command in jenkins

Tags: groovy, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I want to run a groovy command in Jenkins.For which I have  configured groovy through Install automatically.Then I created a free style project and selected Execute groovy script under the build section and then under it I have selected groovy command and have written a simple hello world line.But when I tried executing the job the job history shows `pending-Waiting for next available executor` and I am unable to build the job.Please help me in identifying the problem and do suggest solution.I am pretty new to Groovy.

Comment: I am new to groovy in Jenkins.please mention some links using which i can work on groovy

Answer (score 0):

You need have at least one executor to run your job.

Do you have any slaves? if yes, check if your slave is okej, otherwise, check if your jenkins have free executor.

Comment: You can find it from your jenkins index page, and in the left part, this should have a column called Build Executor Status